# Logic to take a number and create the least combination from available number set

Tags: javascript

I am working on some javascript code where I need to determine the least amount of cable types for an amount of tiles to wire. The cable types available are 3, 4 or 5 Tile cables. I am taking the set and feeding them into an array. Note there will be some cases where there will only be Cable Types of 3, 4

**Example with Cable Types available: 3, 4, 5**

Examples: NumTiles = 21
answer:[5,5,5,3,3]

Example NumTiles: 11
Answer: [4,4,3]

Example NumTiles: 12
Answer [ 4, 4, 4]

Example NumTiles: 22
Answer: [5,5,4,4,4]

Example NumTiles: 7
Answer [4,3]

Example NumTiles: 33
Answer [5,5,5,5,5,5,3]

**Example with Cable Types available: 3, 4**

Example NumTiles: 10
Answer [4,3,3]

Example NumTiles: 17
Answer [4,4,3,3,3]

Example NumTiles: 22
Answer [4,4,4,4,3,3]

Comment: Did I miss the question in here somewhere? Also, what attempts have you made - where is your code? StackOverflow is a resource for helping you debug your issues, not a code-writing service. This question is likely going to be downvoted and/or closed unless you can resolve the various issues it currently suffers from. Some useful resources for you: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry I was wrong not enough coffee.. the correct way would be the [4,4,4,4,3,3] you mentioned. I will edit post not to mention that since it seems you could adjust with the 4 and 3 's to not any additional cable numbers.

Comment: Do you want to optimize for cable _types_ or number of cable pieces? So is `22=[4,4,4,4,3,3]` better than `22=[5,5,5,4,3]`?

Comment: I am optimizing for cable pieces. [5,5,5,4,3] would be the better option as long as 5 cable type is available.

Comment: @Santi I started some code with a lot of if statements and using Modulus and I felt like it wasn't the right approach that is why I asked the question here. I was getting cases where I was having an extra amount of cables at the end so I don't think my code would be useful.

Comment: The purpose of this website is to post your non-working code so we can steer you in the right direction and tell you where you went wrong. If you read the resources I posted above, this entire site is based around you posting your "bad" code.

Comment: Here is a link to the code I started but it is not working very well at all. [JsFiddle - setCableTypeRemainder](https://jsfiddle.net/djc998/u6456zjz/)

Comment: @DennisCafiero , why did you remove " Example NumTiles: 22 Answer [4,4,4,4,4,3] - Note Least amount possible totals 23 which is ok because only 6 cables used total xtra number will just not be wired. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem :

```
var cable_types = [3, 4, 5];
cable_types = cable_types.sort().reverse();
var total = 21;
var final = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < cable_types.length ; i++)
{
    while((total - cable_types[i]) >= 0)
    {
        final.push(cable_types[i]);
        total -= cable_types[i];
    }
}
if(total > 0)
{
    final.push(cable_types[cable_types.length-1]);
}
console.log(final);
```

Comment: If you're going to do this, why not just `21%5` and then figure out if you need a `4` or `3`?

Comment: For that I have already sorted the array , high to low @Halcyon

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst , question is just edited , previous scenario was 

Example NumTiles: 22 Answer [4,4,4,4,4,3] - Note Least amount possible totals 23 which is ok because only 6 cables used total xtra number will just not be wired.

Comment: @VivekDoshi Your code is returning a 3 at the end of every array set. For example I put in total = 30 and it came back as [5,5,5,5,5,3]

Comment: @DennisCafiero , try out with total 20, 25 , 24

Comment: @DennisCafiero, yes it is because of this scenario "Example NumTiles: 22 Answer [4,4,4,4,4,3] - Note Least amount possible totals 23 which is ok because only 6 cables used total xtra number will just not be wired." , that you just removed from your question

Comment: @VivekDoshi 20 comes back with [5,5,5,3] and 25 comes back with [5,5,5,5,3] and 24 comes back with [5,5,5,5,3]

Comment: @DennisCafiero , sorry for the problem , please try now.

Comment: @VivekDoshi This works better and gives me something to work with. The only issue is lets say I have 31 your program returns [5,5,5,5,5,5,3] Better answer would be [5,5,5,5,5,3,3] because then I would not have any unwired cables. I might be able to work with what you have and do a check on total cables and make adjustments.

Comment: I am marking Vivek's correct but here is a link to the JSFiddle that adjusts it so that there is no extra cables. [https://jsfiddle.net/djc998/vo3qkd1v/21/](https://jsfiddle.net/djc998/vo3qkd1v/21/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have cables of length 3, 4, 5 these are base smallest numbers you can make:

```
cables length 
55         10 
344        11 // is 335 better?
345        12 // is 444 better?
3           3
4           4
5           5
33          6
34          7
44          8 // is 35 better?
45          9
```

Any larger numbers can be made by picking the corresponding set from the list and adding the remainder as sets of `5`. So to make `32` you take `345 + 55 + 55`.

You can make a similar base list for 3, 4:

```
cables length
433        10
443        11
444        12
3           3
4           4
4443       15
33          6
43          7
44          8
333         9
4333       13
4433       14
4444       16
44333      17
44433      18
44443      19
44444 20
```

Since we can't use 2 `5`s you can use `44444` to make `20`. Mix and match to get the your desired length.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst just do modulo? Example: `[3,4](99)`: `99%20=19` and `99/20=4` so: `44444|44444|44444|44444|44443`. That's not NP hard. That's not even `O(n)`. That's `O(1)`.